# how to reverse an encoding algorithm

Tags: python

i have the below encryption written in python, i need to write a function to reverse  the output (decryption function)

the main issue im having is with the decoded[i] and hexadecimal_number from what i understood the and bit-wise operation is unrecoverable. im honestly not sure i fully understand what this code is doing regarding the or operation.   it would be great if someone could explain what exactly is happening
here and how to reverse it.

(code)

```
def encrypt(str):

  decoded = bytearray(str.encode('utf-8'))

  for i in range(len(decoded)):
     decoded[i] = ((decoded[i] & 0xF0) >> 4) | ((decoded[i] & 0x0F) << 4)

  return base64.b64encode(decoded).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: From what I can see, it's basically swapping the first 4 bits and the last 4 bits. Should be reversible in exactly the same way really.

Comment: `decoded` is a misleading variable name, as is plainly shown, it is the utf-8 encoded bytes of the input string.  Also, the rightshift `>> 4` if done alone is unrecoverable as 4 bits are lost, but deceze is right that the function is just swapping the bits, and they can be swapped back

Comment: @Hymns "Encryption" is a badly chosen term for this entire operation…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward, as every operation is easily reversible:

```py
def decode(encoded):
    decoded = bytearray(base64.b64decode(encoded))

    for i in range(len(decoded)):
        decoded[i] = ((decoded[i] & 0xF0) >> 4) | ((decoded[i] & 0x0F) << 4)

    return decoded.decode('utf-8')
```

```py
>>> decode(encrypt('asdf'))
'asdf'
```